# jQuery Spell Checker plugin for TinyMCE in .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, tinymce, ckeditor, spell-checking

We have an app written in .NET/MVC (C#) and it uses TinyMCE as the WYSIWYG editor. Works fine except no spell checking natively. The current options are pretty limited (iespell for IE but requires ActiveX, or spellchecker for PHP).

I stumbled on [this site](http://jquery-spellchecker.badsyntax.co/tinymce.html) and it looked promising until I read the documentation and saw that it also requires PHP on the backend.

So I'm looking for an alternative - jQuery plug-in that will work with a .NET backend or possibly replacing TinyMCE and using CKEditor which supports SCAYT.

Anyone have any idea if there is a good jQuery plugin to use or am I possibly stuck with ripping out TinyMCE and replacing it with CKEditor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [typo.js](http://www.chrisfinke.com/2011/03/31/announcing-typo-js-client-side-javascript-spellchecking/), you can use to detect if a word is misspelled and also to get a list of suggestions, but you will have to handle the replacement yourself. I am using it with CodeMirror in my asp.net Mvc project

Answer (score 1):

To anyone coming on this post later:

TinyMCE can now use the browser's built in spell checking functionality, just turn on the option as follows:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
  browser_spellcheck: true
});
```

More details in the [relevant section of the official documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/get-started/spell-checking/#browser-basedspellchecking).

You should then get the red squigglies in the browser:

[image]